# Draggable jQuery-ui doesn't work, despite no error in the console and all files loaded correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use Wordpres. In the console I have no errors. In the sources I can see the files loaded. The only weird thing I see is when I try to add the below on the console appears an error that says that `draggable is not a function`.

```
$(function(){
  $(".page-description-box").draggable();
)};
```

I have this code but it doesn't work

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script typle="text/javascript">
  $(".page-description-box").draggable();
</script>


<div class="page-description-box">
  <p>
    La fotografia documenta tutto, descrive tutto, riflette tutto, dal primo atomo all’universo, dalla pace alla guerra, dalla solitudine individuale alla moltitudine degli eventi sociali. La fotografia libera completamente le capacità di espressione del
    fotografo e lo rende non un mero scattino ma l’autore di quanto egli intende raccontare.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Put your code in a document.ready handler. `$(function() { /* your code here... */ });`

Comment: I'd also suggest you familiarise yourself with jQuery basics: http://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: tried, and now every time I click comes out this error: "Uncaught TypeError: c.replace is not a function ....."

Comment: That's because you're using an absolutely ancient version of jQuery - it's 6 years old. If you update it to 1.12 then it works: https://jsfiddle.net/gL9jmLkk/

Comment: Great, write the answer than I'll vote you, please my question maybe will help someone, can you remove your vote down?

Comment: I added an answer for you, although the vote down wasn't from me.

Comment: Another doubt, I tried to add this to drag only in one direction, the console said me "missing ) after argument list" the code are:   $( document ).ready( function() {
     $( "#contents-home-container-inner" ).draggable(axis: "x");
  var axis = $( "#contents-home-container-inner" ).draggable( "option", "axis" );
  $( "#contents-home-container-inner" ).draggable( "option", "axis", "x" );
  });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138918/discussion-between-sasha-chirico-and-rory-mccrossan).

Comment: You need to wrap the options in braces: `.draggable({ axis: 'x' });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues. Firstly you need to wrap your jQuery code in a document.ready event handler. Secondly you need to upgrade the version of jQuery you're using. 1.5.1 is 6 years old and not compatible with jQueryUI 1.11.4 - hence the error regarding `c.replace is not a function`. Try this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script typle="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $(".page-description-box").draggable();
  })
</script>

<div class="page-description-box">
  <p>
    La fotografia documenta tutto, descrive tutto, riflette tutto, dal primo atomo all’universo, dalla pace alla guerra, dalla solitudine individuale alla moltitudine degli eventi sociali. La fotografia libera completamente le capacità di espressione del
    fotografo e lo rende non un mero scattino ma l’autore di quanto egli intende raccontare.
  </p>
</div>
```